# ajax get a return value of php code

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have here my AJAX code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: type,
    data: data,
    success: function(response){
        if ($returnValue == "success") {
            alert("+");
        }
        else {
            alert("-");
        }
    }
});
```

The code works. But how can i get a value in `$returnValue` via PHP? Something like this dont't work:

PHP

```
<?php return $returnValue; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your php needs to output what you want to return:

```
echo $returnValue;
```

or, for multiple values (this needs to be parsed in javascript):

```
echo json_encode($returnValue);
```

And then the value will be available in `response`:

```
    ...
    success: function(response){
       console.log(response);
       ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I tried is, but i don't work. If you want to know what i mean, look at the comments below Rory's answer.

Comment: @Name What is the exact output you get when you use `console.log(response);`?

Comment: I wrote a comment under Rory's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you need to `echo` the value you want to return in PHP:

```
<?php echo $returnValue; ?>
```

Then in JS it will be assigned to the parameter you defined in the success handler function, in your case `response`. Try this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: type,
    data: data,
    success: function(response) {
        if ($.trim(response) == "success") {
            alert("+");
        } else {
            alert("-");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer! I tried it alot now, but i don't work. I wrote this in my PHP file now `$returnValue = "success";echo $returnValue;` and i have copied your AJAX code.

Comment: Have you checked the console for any error messages?

Comment: Yes, firebug give no errors. I could write my whole php file into the question, but i think its to much? And its useless (i think so), because i added this 2 line's code at the end of the php file.

Comment: @Name You should check the exact response of the ajax call in the console. Any other output (like spaces, new-lines or php warnings) will cause your `if` condition to fail.

Comment: @jeroen good point. I updated my example to trim whitespace from the received text.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan That's like putting a band aid on instead of fixing the actual problem ;-)

Comment: If I write `console.log(response)`, I get the the value inside the variable `$returnValue`. Something with the if/else is wrong? Because the return value is correct.

Comment: @jeroen very true :) Ideally OP should change the response to JSON.

Comment: That means, i have to use JSON?

Comment: You don't have to, but it's better practice

Comment: I think i have to, because it don't work at the moment despite the return value is correct. Then I will search now how I can parse(?) it.  Thanks for you help.

Comment: One question. I made a third `=` in the if/else construct and it works. Here the code: `if(response === "success"){
            alert("sehr gut");
        }
        else{
            alert("nicht gut");
        }`, why is this working?

Comment: See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Identity_.2F_strict_equality_(.3D.3D.3D)

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you.

```
$.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: type,
            data: data,
            success: function(data){
                if(data.response == "success"){
                    alert("+");
                }
                else{
                    alert("-");
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Note that OP is attempting to return a singular text value, not an object

Answer (score 0):

In your Js file :

```
$.ajax({
url: "file.php", //Point your php file
dataType: "text",
    success: function(response) {
    if ($.trim(response) == "success") {
        alert("+");
    } else {
        alert("-");
    }
}
```

});

In your `file.php`

```
header("Content-Type: text/plain");
echo "success";
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it don't work too. Is it important, that the AJAX type = post?

Comment: Try to console.log the answer from your php file

Comment: I wrote `console.log(response)`. And the output is correct. But something with the if else is wrong.

Comment: Test the value of response var : `success: function(response) { console.log(response) }`
If it's okay, add an third equal sign '=' that will assure that the type of response is text.
 `if ($.trim(response) === "success")`